# Examples of homogeneous polynomials that define $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, toric-geometry

The complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ is also a projective variety. According to Hartshorne, a projective variety is defined a s the zero set of a subset of homogeneous polynomials defined on $\mathbb{C}^n$ (he uses a generic algebraically close field $k$ but I prefer to study $\mathbb{C}$.

Can you give me an example of such polynomials whose zero set is understood as $\mathbb{P}^n$?

That is, I would especially like to understand the cases of $\mathbb{P}^2$, $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ (and more general Hirzebruch surfaces) as zero sets of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}[x_0, \ldots]$ rather than topological spaces using the standard equivalence relations.

Comment: Almost tautologically, since $\Bbb P^2$ is the projectivization of $\Bbb C^3$, $\Bbb P^2$ is (the projectivization of) the zero set of the zero polynomial on $\Bbb C^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am not sure this helps me a lot (physicist here). I would like to see something more concrete if possible, that is an example of how a set of polynomials (with some representatives maybe) define the projective varieties.

Comment: Have you looked at the Veronese embeddings?

Comment: No, I don't even know what they are.